# "Вновь прибывший" и "новоприбывший", разница

Tags: словообразование, смысл

Обнаружил, что есть слово *"новоприбывший".* Но чем *"новоприбывший"* отличается от *"вновь прибывшего"?* Если ничем, зачем нужны эти два варианта?

Answer (score 2):

Разница в употреблении. В документах употребляется исключительно вариант "**вновь прибывший**", характерный для формального стиля. В остальных случаях этот вариант можно предпочесть, если речь идёт лишь о *предполагаемом* прибытии каких-то людей ("мы их встретим так-то"), в то время как менее формальное "**новоприбывший**" наводит на мысль об *уже* состоявшемся прибытии (возможно даже, по ассоциации с созвучным "новорождённый").

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!

Answer (score 0):

1) **НОВОПРИБЫВШИЙ**,  Только что, недавно прибывший куда-л. Н. гость. Н-ая отпускница поселилась в соседнем номере. Н-ие пассажиры столпились у турникета.

**Это прилагательное,** которое обозначает постоянный (для данного момента) признак и довольно часто переходит с существительное (даже может иметь при себе определение):

Тем не менее, первые советские шаги в этом районе оказались успешными, что объяснить можно только тем, что **наш новоприбывший** воспользовался какой-то агентурной сетью ... [И. А. Бродский. Коллекционный экземпляр (1991)].
Юрий Азагаров решил в уме, что **новоприбывший гость,** должно быть, очень важный господин... [И. Куприн. Тапер (1900)].

2) **Вновь прибывший** ― это причастие с зависимым словом, которое имеет значение действия, **более универсальная форма**. (Иногда может соотноситься с сущ., хотя и реже, чем новоприбывший):

**Вновь прибывший инженер** Костько был допрошен очень подробно. [В. К. Кетлинская. Мужество (1934-1938)]. **Вновь прибывший пастор,** англичанин же, объявил, что судно пришло из Гон-Конга,  [И. А. Гончаров. Фрегат «Паллада» (1855)] . Им пришлось признать, что **вновь прибывший** лучше всех понимал положение рабов. [И. А. Ефремов. На краю Ойкумены (1945-1946)]

Comment: Спасибо, Сибилла! А зачем запятая после "тем не менее"? И что значит "соотноситься с сущ."? С существительным или -ми? В любом случае я плохо понимаю, что значит соотноситься.

Comment: Новоприбывший - это существительное (переход прилагат.  в  сущ.), а "вновь прибывший" - это (при отсутствии определяемого слова) СОЧЕТАНИЕ с предметным значением, тоже как у сущ. По поводу "тем не менее": это цитата; в современных словарях обособление не рекомендуется, но в текстах в начале предложения очень часто встречается обособленный вариант. Ну чем не вводное слово?

Comment: Понятно всё, спасибо! Даже не сообразил сразу, что это не Ваши слова, но всё равно мне нужно было это объяснение. Всё-таки у "тем не менее" вначале смысл(,) как у "однако". (Тут запятая нужна, не скажете? Спасибо!) А после "однако" запятую не ставят в таком случае. Или есть разница?

Comment: В запятой сомневаюсь из-за отсутствия паузы.

Comment: Я просмотрела тексты с "тем не менее": в большинстве случаев обособления нет, но при этом  выражение так встроено в текст, что пауза не требуется.  Обособление делается в том случае, если   без пауз текст "не читается", например: "Тем не менее, всё-таки пред нами остается вопрос…(Достоевский). "Юпитер, тем не менее, занимался одними только человеческими делами: играл в винт, пил горькую и прохаживался по части клубнички" (Чехов). Поэтому нельзя простоты ради утверждать, что не обособляется никогда. Еще простой пример: "В избе послышались вздохи. Тем не менее, дверь открывалась".

Comment: Убедительно, спасибо, только в последнем я не чувствую паузы. А про запятую подскажете (которая в скобках у меня в комментарии)?

Comment: И ещё: Вы согласны с Александром в том, что "вновь прибывший" больше характерно для формального стиля?

Comment: Я думаю, что "новоприбывший" используется в качестве термина в деловом стиле, например: "Новоприбывшие курсанты полностью укомплектованы техническими средствами". "Для самих молодых новоприбывших призывников  будут продолжать действовать любые консультации касаемо всех вопросов связанных с призывами, самой военной службой, с вопросами по медицинскому освидетельствованию".

Comment: Спасибо! То есть Вы считаете почти наоборот с ним! Хм...

Comment: Да нет, не наоборот, просто я различаю слово и словосочетание. "Новоприбывший" по структуре  похоже на термин, но и в разговорной речи тоже используется, иногда с оттенком иронии. А словосочетание универсально и не имеет добавочных смысловых или стилистических значений.

Comment: Понятно, Сибилла, спасибо!